# Is there a way to extract coordinates of a moving object

Tags: physics

I'm doing material composition research in blender. I wanted to know if there was a way to exact the coordinates of a moving object. Right now it's giving me the initial starting coordinate of the object for all time points of the physics animation simulation. Anything helps! [image][image]

Comment: What kind of physics is it?  Rigid body?  Softbody, cloth?

Comment: do you mean extract?

Comment: And the coordinates of the separate elements, or just the volume?

Answer (score 0):

if it is a rigid body simulation, you can e.g. add a custom attribute, add a driver with these settings:

[image]

which gives you the x location.

Just add two more with y and z and you got the whole location.

[image]

if you wanna use animation nodes, it is a bit nicer and quicker:

[image]

[image]

especially if you wanna watch more objects, animation nodes is very supportive:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in the transform field isn't the final, "visual" transform.  It's the number after your manipulations, reading the f-curve, and any drivers.  But rigid body physics and constraints act on top of this number.

If we want the location at some particular point in the animation, just because we're curious about the location, we can use "apply visual transform" operation:

[image]

I'm using this from the ctrl-a menu.  It applies the visual transform to our actual transform fields.  If we don't want this to change our animations, we'd want to undo after reading that value.

If we want a complete description of the locations of our rigid bodies, we can use a rigid body "bake to keyframes" operation to write the (visual) transform of physics into keyframes:

[image]

This will *replace* our existing physics with keyframes-- once you do this, your physics will no longer respond to changes you make in the scene.  Because you won't have any physics on anything that you baked, just keyframes.

If we wanted to have something readable, live, that didn't alter the physics in any way, we'd want an object with "transform channel" type driver, which reads the visual transform of an object.  Chris's method works; my personal way would be like this:

[image]

That driver copies the world space X location of the cube onto the empty.  If I also copy the Y and Z, I have the full location of the cube.  The output of the driver shows up in the transform fields of the empty, as shown.

We could do something similar with a GN object-- GN nodes see visual transforms, so we could read them there, and output them in GN however we'd like.

And there's one final method, which is, maybe I don't need the actual numbers, I just need to *put* something there.  In which case, constraints will also target the visual transform of objects:

[image]

Just like physics objects, constrained objects can have their constraints "baked" to keyframes or have visually applied transforms.